# App details in store

Tags: android, android-8.0-oreo, android-install-apk

In Android 8 there is a new section called "App details in store" (Settings -> Apps -> select an app). The apps installed from Google Play has setted this field to: App downloaded from Google Play Store.

Apps installed from Amazon: App downloaded from Amazon Appstore.

But when I install an app from my own app, this is the message: App downloaded from Package installer

Some screenshots:
[image: screenshot1]

[image: screenshot2]

[image: screenshot3]

[image: screenshot4]

[image: screenshot5]

I've setted Intent.EXTRA_INSTALLER_PACKAGE_NAME but the result is:
[image]

I would like to set my app name in this field: App downloaded from "MyAppName"

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: looks like you forgot to ask a question.

Comment: true! I want to set my app name: App downloaded from AppName XD

Comment: Did you find any solution for this? I'm also facing the exact same problem. I am only able to change this value on older versions using the setInstallerPackageName on null installer package names.

Comment: @jdandradex no, I couldn't find a solution :-(

Comment: I've seen that by using Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSTALL_PACKAGE) with intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INSTALLER_PACKAGE_NAME, "installer.package.name") we are able to set this value for older API versions, without the need of setInstallerPackageName from PackageManager. Unfortunately, it does not seem to be working on higher versions, where the installer package name is again the PackageInstaller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved! Its possible set the name of my app as installer using the installation method implemented in 
[Split APKs Installer](https://github.com/Aefyr/SAI)

Answer (score 0):

It is a name of the *application installer* application.

Like which app has installed this app into the phone:

1. In case of Google Play - google play app has installed this app on your phone.
2. In case of Amazon - Amazon app installed this app to your phone.
3. In case of installation from APK - Package Manager app has installed it in your phone.

So if you want your app to be listed there - you will have to create an application, which is able to install other applications. It has to be a system app, because only system apps can install other apps.

Comment: Amazon is NOT a system app

Comment: @cgr so how does it install other apps? Does it launch package manager to do that?

Comment: I do not know how amazon does it, I would like to know

Comment: @cgr does it show the screen where it shows another app's (Package Manager's) screen asking if you want to install this apk?

Comment: yes, it shows the screen asking for install/cancel. But I noticed that Amazon hides this screen when the user click on install. I've installed amazon on my device, for this reason i know is NOT a system app, and the device is NOT rooted

Comment: @cgr, looks like I'm wrong. Probably the APK itself contains some metadata about where was it downloaded from